# how to get geographical location from co-ordinates using jde 4.5

Tags: blackberry, gps, location, jde, gis

How can I get the geographical location (Address) from the co-ordinates in Blackberry jde 4.5.

Thanks and regards,
Vivek Birdi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Location API](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/location/) to obtain the GPS Co-Ordinates and then use a [reverse geocoding](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse%5FGeocoding%5F.2F%5FAddress%5Flookup) service to obtain the address.

Answer (score 0):

You do http get to Google geo on 
[Google geo](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html#Geocoding)

the response can be either JSON or XML according to  your need , I prefer JSON since it more light weight for Mobile communication